# C++ Cannot call member function inside the class

Tags: c++, static-methods

I'm wondering why it's not possible to call a member function from a static function

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
public:
  A(){}
  ~A(){}
  static void astaticFunction(){
    printHello();
  }

private:
  void printHello(){
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
  }

};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  A::astaticFunction();
  return 0;

}
```

the compiler is returning this

```
main.cpp: In static member function ‘static void A::astaticFunction()’:
main.cpp:8:16: error: cannot call member function ‘void A::printHello()’ without object
```

And how can I use it ?
Thanks

Comment: How could it possibly?  What would the value of the `this` pointer be?

Comment: printHello() can't magically be called inside a static method. Compiler doesn't know wich A object to call, since you haven't create anyone. You need something inside your static method like: A a; a.printHello()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only call other static member functions from inside a static member function. This is because a non-static member function is associated with a particular instance of the object. Here you don't have an instance.

So one quick fix is to make `printHello` static:

```
static void printHello(){
  std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}
```

If you *need* `printHello` to work on a particular instance of `A` (because perhaps in your real code it uses a non-static data member), then you need to create that instance. You could do that like so:

```
static void astaticFunction(){
  A a; // Create an A object
  a.printHello();
}
```

Comment: Or pass it as a parameter to astaticFunction.

Answer (score 0):

As sftrabbit said, you cannot access non static members from static member functions. Just as an explanation as to why, non-static member functions are called using calling convention that passes *this* (instance pointer) implicitly. So when you call them, apart from defined arguments, there's a hidden *this* argument.